# How to add a space between the words "HTML" and "CSS" on the example below?

Tags: javascript

```js
let languages = ["HTML", "CSS", "JavaScript"];

function FooterFunction() {
  document.querySelector(".footer-Paragraph").innerHTML = "This page was built using: " + languages.slice(0, -1) + " and " + languages.slice(-1);
}

FooterFunction()
```

```html
<div class="footer-Paragraph"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [array.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```
languages.slice(0,-1).join(", ")
```